# collectionview - attempt to delete item 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 items before the update

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, crash, collectionview

i am trying to delete lines from the horizontal collectionview on index basis, the other index remove easily but when i remove the last index it throws this exception[image]

here is my deletion code only two lines, i tried multiple solutions but nothing works for me, i delete cell before removing index, also try **performBatchUpdates**
[image]

Comment: i also check index, nothing wrong with the index everything is fine, it is multiuser application, on the other logins it perform well but on specific user it generating issue

Comment: You can't have a section with 0 items. If you are removing the last item from the section you have to delete the section.  Also, please don't post images of code. They can't be copied into answers, indexed/searched and they don't work with screen readers.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok i kept in mind next time not to post images only code, regarding to your answer i can't get your point why should i remove the section while i am not using any section(default behaviour), Issue is only with the delete button of the last index in my horizontal collection view, even on the delete button of last index i try to remove the index 0 from the array and then reload my collectionview it gets the same exception.

Comment: If the array has 0 items in it you need to ensure that `numberOfSections` returns 0 (assuming you have only 1 section)

Comment: while i am getting this exception array count not equal to zero, i if try to delete index from 0 to n then not populate any exception, even if i delete index at n-1 also no error error only populate at index n removing r deletion, 
for deep understanding of my issue i set a bool flag into array "lineDeletion" and set it true and just reload the collection on deletion click and remove that index on the basis of "lineDeletion" numberOfItemsInSection and return but got no luck

Comment: The exception tells you what is going wrong; you have removed the last item from the section but not removed the section.  You `numberOfSections` needs to be something like `return getLedgerList[0].postingLinesArr.isEmpty ? 0:1` Of course if you have more than 1 section it gets more complicated.

Comment: i try **return getLedgerList[0].postingLinesArr.isEmpty ? 0:1** but still stuck there, thanks for your help
please let me know if any other solution is possible for this exception.

Answer (score -1):

Check the index that is passed to remove.
It is due to the index value passed which is greater than the items count in the array.

Comment: index count is ok, having array count 2 and i am also getting error when i am removing at index  1. 
i also try to set check only remove when the index is less than array count